# Trouble counting the number of keys in a hash reference

Tags: perl

I am trying to calculate the number of elements in a scalar variable which stores a reference to a hash:

```
$result = $test->call($val);
```

I have tried `keys %result`, `keys $result`. But this has failed.

My understanding is that `$result` is a scalar variable storing reference to an anonymous hash, because

```
print "Test $results \n";
```

gives

```
Test YYY::ZZZ::AAA=HASH(0x1133d80)
```

Comment: You have to dereference the hash reference. `keys %$result`.

Comment: The example code is very incomplete, so it's hard to say, but `scalar keys %hash` should do it.

Answer (score 10):

`keys %result` passes the wrong hash.

`keys $result` doesn't pass a hash.

You need `keys %$result`.

References:

- [Mini-Tutorial: Dereferencing Syntax](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=977408)
- [References quick reference](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927)
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)
- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to de-reference as follows using {}

```
    %{$result}
```

I understood this from below link, http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/dereferencing.html